# How to select the sequence of digits from string in Firebird 2.5?

Tags: regex, firebird, firebird2.5

I have strings like:

```
26.05.2016/00002Lol
26.05.2016/00003(Lol)
26.05.2016UUUU/00004(Lol)
```

How to select the sequence of five digits (`00002, 00003, 00004`) from these strings?

Comment: With Firebird 3 you might be able to do it with [the new regex feature for `SUBSTRING`](http://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/bk01ch09s05.html#rnfb30-dml-substring); I haven't tried it though. For 2.5 I'd strongly consider solving this in your application layer, or writing your own UDF to extract it.

Answer (score 4):

Are those five digits always after the first `'/'`?  If so, then:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col FROM POSITION(col, '/') + 1 FOR 5) AS fivedigits ...
```

ought to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

## Description

```
(?<=\/)[0-9]{5}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- capture the first 5 digits after the `\` character

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/lD6pW5/1

**Sample text**

```
26.05.2016/00002Lol
26.05.2016/00003(Lol)
26.05.2016UUUU/00004(Lol)
```

**Sample Matches**

```
[0][0] = 00002
[1][0] = 00003
[2][0] = 00004
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{5}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (5 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This won't work in Firebird without custom UDFs.  Only Firebird 3.0 supports regexes in SUBSTRING, and even then only SQL-style regexes (which lack lookbehind support and in Firebird requires an explicitly defined escape character).